# Can I upload my google play apps to other stores?

Tags: android, google-play

Is it ok to share app in other app markets ?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming

Comment: This does not seem to be a programming questions. Please see the following link on how to ask proper questions on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for info :) I asked because stackoverflow is the best !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. I actually use the same APKs across Amazon and Google Play both. Only thing that varies is on Amazon Store you can't brand Google Play stuff in the App itself. Like you can't have a link inside saying rate on Google Play. My apk got rejected for mentioning the Google Play store inside of my Amazon Market App.

You can also sign using your keystore/key and use those signed APKs in Amazon Market. The approval process takes slightly longer on Amazon than Google Play.

There are also quite a few other markets and APK download places that let you use the same binaries!

Also if you target different devices like Fire TV, and other Android devices, be sure to consider those non traditional Android OS platforms.

Also Amazon has game circle vs google play services for leaderboards, etc. Although you can use google play services for leaderboards and such across Android (even iOS) platforms.

I have numerous apps and games (native and Unity) that use same APKs! Keep vigil that file sizes differ too. With Play you can put expansion packs over a certain Megabyte, but the binary has to be under a certain size for both stores. There's a specific size for cellular downloads, and wifi downloads I believe. It used to be 50MB, but maybe it's 100MB now, I'm not sure.

This question should be on a different dev forum exchange, and perhaps SO isn't an appropriate place for this type of question, but one of the more broader programming and app development exchanges.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can submit your app to other stores.

If you want to publish your app to another store e.g Amazon, there are specific guidelines you will have to follow. Such as creating a new Amazon app profile. You will also have to sign your release apk differently.

https://developer.amazon.com/public/support/submitting-your-app

Answer (score 0):

You can do with your apps whatever you want